# Given the quarter number and year, how to find the date ranges?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying create a function that will return date ranges if I pass in the quarter number (1,2,3, or 4) and the year for that quarter.

Here is what I have so far:

```
export const getCurrentQuarterRangeString = (quarter, year) => {
  // let year = moment().year(year);
  let start = moment().quarter(quarter).startOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  let end = moment().quarter(quarter).endOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  let dateRangeString = `${start};#${end}`;
  return dateRangeString;
}
```

I get tripped up on trying to figure out how to key off that year parameter for MomentJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a moment when you pass a year into your function. Use that to manipulate and get you required dates.

```
const moment = require("moment");

export const getCurrentQuarterRangeString = (quarter, year) => {
  const yearObject = moment(parseInt(year), "YYYY");

  const startOfQuater = yearObject.quarter(quarter).startOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  const endOfQuarter = yearObject.quarter(quarter).endOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  return `${start};#${end}`;
}
```

Comment: Also what is the reasoning behind ```const moment = require("moment");```? I have seen that before but never really knew what that does. Will research it here in a bit

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the moment with a date from your desired year

```
export const getCurrentQuarterRangeString = (quarter, year) => {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setFullYear(year);
  moment = moment(d);

  let start = moment.quarter(quarter).startOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  let end = moment.quarter(quarter).endOf('quarter').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  let dateRangeString = `${start};#${end}`;
  return dateRangeString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, its giving me a reference error whenever I try that function: ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Comment: Have you imported moment?

Comment: Yep, it is imported in the file that I am exporting the function from. ```import moment from "moment";```

Comment: seems like an import issue, can you put the whole code in the question?

Comment: Sure thing, I've added the necessary code. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Comment: I would say you shouldn't be reassigning the `moment` name; just create a new variable for the new variable representing the year.